# Darts Program in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I would like to create a program for darts, I walked up to a problem.

```
s1 := Form1.Edit1.Text;
s2 := Form1.Edit2.Text;
s3 := Form1.Edit3.Text;
x1 := StrToFloat(s1);
x2 := StrToFloat(s2);
x3 := StrToFloat(s3);
score1 := (score1 - x1 - x2 - x3);
ss1 := FloatToStr(score1);
Form1.Edit7.Text := ss1;
```

score1 should be 501 at start and count down, so score 1 is at the start 501 you fill in 3 numbers and it should be 501-1-1-1 (for example) and then the next time it should be 498-1-1-1

How can i do this?

I dont have any problems or errors, i just dont know how to do this.

I use lazarus to write the program.

I hope i explained this well enough.

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: What is your q, exactly?

Comment: your piece of code does not show a specific problem - we do not see your texteditds nor do I see a concrete problem with it. You need some kind of loop or eventhandler on your text-.fields. It is not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will outline how you might do this, but leave the coding up to you.

First you need to read up about programming loops - see for example

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_loops.htm

Typically, with a task like this, you start by setting some initial condition(s) before the loop first executes.  In your case, I think it would be better to back-track slightly from there and choose a better name for your `score` variable.  Personally, I would base the name on `Target`, and actually have two variables, `Target`, that you initialize before the loop (to 501) and `RunningTarget` that you initialize to equal `Target` before the loop, and update each time around the loop (as in your `score1 := (score1 - x1 - x2 - x3)`)

The type of loop - see the article - is up to you.  It will need a `terminating condition` which decodes whether to continue looping or to stop.  Again that's for you to decide and code.

Finally, you need to think about why you feel the need to call `FloatToStr` and what you are trying to achieve by this - after all the `RunningTotal`'s value will be a whole number, won't it?

Have fun!

Btw, the reason I suggested thinking about a different variable name is that you should always have in the back of your mind whether it will mean the same thing to you in 6 months' time - or to another reader.  To me, 'score' sounds like the value should be increasing, whereas your code will do the exact opposite.